# Считывание уже выведенного в консоль текста

Tags: c#

Допустим у нас есть текст, который вывелся в консоль.
Можно ли его как-либо вернуть в переменную? Пример:

```
Console.Write("123456789");
```

Допустим мы ставим курсор перед "6", и заменяем ее на другой символ. Спустя какое-то количество времени нам надо исправить этот текст обратно на "6", но сделать мы это не может, потому, что не знаем, какой именно символ там был(мы не должны высчитывать и знать). Как поместить в переменную то, что находится впереди (сзади) относительно курсора, если это вообще возможно?
Да, думаю, можно выводить не текст а переменную

```
string Write = "123456789";
Console.Write(Write);
```

Но такой способ не очень подходит, ибо не хочется перерисовывать все строку.

Если подобного способа нет, то как "отодрать" от переменной несколько символов. Допустим у нас была `string Write = "q2wer4t56yui8";`, как нам убрать, допустим 5 символов в начале переменной(символы за ранее не известны).

Comment: `s.Substring(5)`?

Comment: @VladD Да, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считывать символы, уже выведенные на консоль, можно, но это достаточно сложно. Вам придётся подключать WinAPI, т. к. класс `Console` такой функциональности не предоставляет.

Гораздо проще следить за тем, какой текст вы выводите. Для того, чтобы понять, какой символ в строке по индексу 5, проще всего использовать просто `s[5]`. Если вам нужен «хвост» строки, используйте `s.Substring(5)`.

Comment: P.S. Завести переменную, которая будет хранить в себе всё, что Вы выводите на консоль...

Comment: @EgorTrutnev: Именно так.